# Executing a bat file inside a Stored Procedure using SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server

When i try to execute a bat file using xp_CMDShell, i am getting a message as not recognized command.

Following is the command i executed:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'C:\Documents and Settings\adcxqcv\Desktop\PQA\sample.bat'
```

I got a message as follows:

```
'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
NULL
```

Any Suggestions. Let me know how to execute a bat file inside a Stored Procedure.
I am new to SQl Server.

Thanks,
Vinu

Answer (score 6):

Put the path inside ""

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell '"C:\Documents and Settings\adcxqcv\Desktop\PQA\sample.bat"'
```

Answer (score 2):

xp_cmdshell can be a bit picky on the long file names, you are using quotes and it isn't playing ball, double quotes can sometimes work but if it still doesn't want to play ball then try use the older 8.3 filename instead.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'c:\docume~1\adcxqcv\Desktop\PQA\sample.bat'
```

Answer (score -1):

**Without parameter**

```
exec(' xp_cmdshell ''C:\script\test.bat'); --your bat file location(path)
```

**With parameter**

```
exec(' xp_cmdshell ''C:\script\test.bat '+@ecistate+' '+@stateid+' '+@pcno+''''); --your bat file location(path)
```

**Execute and enjoy  the solution:)**