# SQL cmdshell to execute putty command

Tags: sql-server, putty

I am trying to run a sh file in putty ssh from windows which was done successfully using putty and cmd prompt. When trying the same in xp_cmdshell or through sp_start_job in mssql the query is running for longtime without end.

SQL Query:

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'D:\path\run.bat'
```

batch file:

```
"C:\Program Files\Putty\putty.exe" -ssh root@10.10.10.1 -pw mypass -m D:\path\runcmd.txt
```

Is the way I am trying correct?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

`EXEC master..xp_CMDShell '"D:\path\run.bat"'`

details referred from below link,

[Executing a bat file inside a Stored Procedure using SQL server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023625/executing-a-bat-file-inside-a-stored-procedure-using-sql-server-2005)